# MySQL Query on two tables containing different dates

Tags: mysql, join

I've a little issue I cannot handle very well.
I need to export some data from two tables. Both tables are containing only two fields. The first is a datetime, the second contains values.
I would like to graph those data grouping it by dates. Let me explain with an example.

Table A:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA order by Time desc limit 10;
```

output:

```
2016-08-26 12:50:10     27
2016-08-26 12:45:02     26.9
2016-08-26 12:40:04     26.8
2016-08-26 12:35:03     26.5
2016-08-26 12:30:03     27
2016-08-26 12:25:10     27.1
2016-08-26 12:21:28     27.2
2016-08-26 12:20:58     26.9
2016-08-26 12:20:28     27
2016-08-26 12:20:00     26.9
```

Table B:

```
SELECT * FROM tableB order by Time desc limit 10;

2016-08-26 12:56:03     30.1
2016-08-26 12:50:10     29.9
2016-08-26 12:45:02     29.8
2016-08-26 12:42:05     30.1
2016-08-26 12:35:04     30.1
2016-08-26 12:31:03     30
2016-08-26 12:25:11     30
2016-08-26 12:20:01     29.6
2016-08-26 12:17:01     29.6
2016-08-26 12:10:02     29.5
```

As you can see the Time value is not equal. I would like to get values taken from both tables, group and graph them. The graph is not a problem. I would like, in example, take one value per table every 5 minutes.
Any help would be apreciated!

Thanks!

Simon

Comment: Is same time entry in both the table?

Comment: Please show the desired result of query. How close time values have to combine

Comment: Well, the output should be given to a Google Chart with double axis values like that: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart (see Dual-Y Charts). So the output should be something I will then translate in:

    datetime, valuefromA, valuefromB

So maybe I need to round datetime to group.... Those values in this example are similar, but I need a graph that are holding values different and so I need dual-X axis. The tables are btw the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping to 5 minutes (300 seconds). If multiple values fall into one interval take the maximum value.

```
select  from_unixtime(U*300) as date,
        max(if(T='A',val,NULL)) as A_VAL,
        max(if(T='B',val,NULL)) as B_VAL
  from (
    select ceil(unix_timestamp(date)/300) as U, val, 'A' as T
      from tableA
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-08-26 12:20:00' AND '2016-08-26 12:55:00'
    union all
    select ceil(unix_timestamp(date)/300) as U, val, 'B' as T
      from tableB
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-08-26 12:20:00' AND '2016-08-26 12:55:00'
   ) A
 group by U
 order by U
```

Result:

```
2016-08-26 12:15:00 NULL    29.5
2016-08-26 12:20:00 26.900  29.6
2016-08-26 12:25:00 27.200  29.6
2016-08-26 12:30:00 27.100  30.0
2016-08-26 12:35:00 27.000  30.0
2016-08-26 12:40:00 26.500  30.1
2016-08-26 12:45:00 26.800  30.1
2016-08-26 12:50:00 26.900  29.8
2016-08-26 12:55:00 27.000  29.9
2016-08-26 13:00:00 NULL    30.1
```

[Sample on sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9519a/1/0)

Comment: Hello Mike! The result is near perfect. Could you suggest me how to set a timerange as well, i.e. 'WHERE TIME BETWEEN '2016-08-26 12:20:00' AND '2016-08-26 12:55:00'. I got an empty result if I try to specify it.

Comment: @Simon Now in outer query no datetime in suitable format. Only seconds/300 kept there. The best decision (fastest query speed) - specify date condition on read any table. I've updated the answer to reflect this